Querying athena aws the right way
i get a time out queriing https://commoncrawl.org/overview data with athena ... and if it succeed it will cost me 1000$ each query ... 5$ for each TB with 200 TB (?) ... actually too much
This is, what I do :
CREATE DATABASE CommonData20102024;



CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CommonData20102024.commoncrawl_warc (
  WARC_Type           STRING,
  WARC_Date           STRING,
  WARC_Record_ID      STRING,
  Content_Length      INT,
  WARC_Concurrent_To  STRING,
  Content_Type        STRING,
  WARC_Block_Digest   STRING,
  WARC_Payload_Digest STRING,
  WARC_IP_Address     STRING,
  WARC_Refers_To      STRING,
  WARC_Target_URI     STRING,
  WARC_Truncated      STRING,
  WARC_Warcinfo_ID    STRING,
  WARC_Filename       STRING,
  WARC_Profile        STRING,
  WARC_Identified_Payload_Type STRING,
  Payload             STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "..."
)
LOCATION 's3://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2024-38/';


SELECT WARC_Target_URI
FROM ccrawl_db.commoncrawl_warc
WHERE lower(WARC_Target_URI) LIKE '%.de%'

My question: is it the right way accessing that data?  I just want to get the urls with german tld

Looking at Common Crawl - Blog - Index to WARC Files and URLs in Columnar Format, this is certainly one way to access the data. Alternatively, you could copy the data to your own S3 bucket, which would allow you to control which files are accessible.

Following the tutorial, helped me to find the answer:
https://commoncrawl.org/blog/index-to-warc-files-and-urls-in-columnar-format
The following SQL-Statements I used:
CREATE DATABASE ccindex

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ccindex (
  url_surtkey                   STRING,
  url                           STRING,
  url_host_name                 STRING,
  url_host_tld                  STRING,
  url_host_2nd_last_part        STRING,
  url_host_3rd_last_part        STRING,
  url_host_4th_last_part        STRING,
  url_host_5th_last_part        STRING,
  url_host_registry_suffix      STRING,
  url_host_registered_domain    STRING,
  url_host_private_suffix       STRING,
  url_host_private_domain       STRING,
  url_protocol                  STRING,
  url_port                      INT,
  url_path                      STRING,
  url_query                     STRING,
  fetch_time                    TIMESTAMP,
  fetch_status                  SMALLINT,
  content_digest                STRING,
  content_mime_type             STRING,
  content_mime_detected         STRING,
  content_charset               STRING,
  content_languages             STRING,
  warc_filename                 STRING,
  warc_record_offset            INT,
  warc_record_length            INT,
  warc_segment                  STRING)
PARTITIONED BY (
  crawl                         STRING,
  subset                        STRING)
STORED AS parquet
LOCATION 's3://commoncrawl/cc-index/table/cc-main/warc/';

MSCK REPAIR TABLE ccindex

select url
    from ccindex
   where crawl = 'CC-MAIN-2024-38'
     and subset = 'warc'
     and url_host_tld = 'de';

